# A wounded Zombie finder, or: how to find the almost dead undead?

Tags: beginner, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

The [Zombies](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/21002) are on their way to eat our statistics. Fortunately, we have a way to get rid of them: our votes. However, we need to find them first. The [/unanswered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered) section is too large and contains many strong enemies where we have to write a review first. But the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) can sniff almost dead Zombies from a mile.

For this, we need a fitting query. This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  q.Id AS [Post Link],
  MAX(a.Score) AS [Best answer score]
FROM 
  Posts q
JOIN 
  Posts a ON a.ParentId = q.Id
WHERE 
      q.PostTypeId = 1  
  AND q.AnswerCount > 0
  AND q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
  AND a.PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY 
  q.Id
HAVING 
 MAX(a.Score) = 0
```

You can [run and find the query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/825530/possible-insta-kill-zombies).

It searches for questions (`q.PostTypeId = 1`) that have at least one answer, no accepted answer, and the maximum score of all its answers is `0`. The resulting list can then be checked for fast Zombie removal.

Is there something that is utterly wrong? Or can this weapon help us in our fight against the undead?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes they are. I'll try to find a reference but I have seen queries using keywords only available in T-SQL. (sort-of reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54450/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel It's in the help: [*"Click the Compose Query button up there and start typing your __T-SQL query__"*](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#introduction) (if you're looking for it)

Comment: @Zeta thanks. I recently learned there is a [SEDE tutorial](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) you might be interested in. Depending on your SQL knowledge, you can skip some of the pages.

Comment: @Glorfindel If I hadn't read that tutorial, I wouldn't have known the `as [Post Link]` trick ^^. Unfortunately, the tutorial falls short on the `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` site.

Comment: Could you please help with finding wounded C++ zombies? I tried to stick in `  AND q.tags like 'c++' ` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Incomputable [here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/825530/possible-insta-kill-zombies?TagName=c%2B%2B)

Comment: @Zeta, wow, thank you. So I needed to use `tagName` instead of `tags`.

Comment: @Incomputable I'm working on a new variant, but as far as I can see, you have to go over `PostTags`.

Comment: For the record: I just found https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77638/forgotten-zombie-killers, so at least one other member had the same idea :)

Comment: Was excluding questions where all answers score negatively intentional?

Comment: @jpmc26 yes. If a question has a single positive answer it counts as "answered", even if a question hasn't been accepted. This query only looks for questions where a single upvote can change a question from being unanswered to answered (0 -> 1).

Comment: I tried to copy this for SO but it runs out of resources https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/826065/so-injured-android-zombies - the query probably needs simplifying

Comment: @NickCardoso see the follow up question (the sniper). According to rofl, the `HAVING` is bad and should get replaced by a CTE. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: This appears to include closed questions. Is that a bug or intentional?

Comment: @Mast It should report the same as `/unanswered`, except that the result should have at least one answer with a score of `0`. If `/unanswered` does not contain closed questions and this query does, then it's a (previously unknown) bug :/.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not utterly wrong, but

```
q.PostTypeId = 1
```

and

```
AND a.PostTypeId = 2
```

are superfluous. The only post types with a non-null value in `ParentId` are answers (see the [Database schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232)), and their values are the ids of questions, so the join already takes care of this.

I'd slightly misunderstood the objective of the query at first, because questions with answers with negative scores, like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/11138/69714) also appear on /unanswered. But you want to review the answers to see if they're worthy of an upvote. Then, you might as well drop the second column (`MAX(a.Score) AS [Best answer score]`) because you *know* it's going to be zero.

Comment: Yeah, I should drop the `[Best answer score]`. My first variant was similar to `/unanswered`, but then I thought it would be better just to look for those fast zombie removal questions. I've opted to use `q.Tags` instead in a [newer variant](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/825530/possible-insta-kill-zombies), although I'm pretty sure that I'm abusing `GROUP BY`. But that's for a future review. Thanks already for your remarks.